# Horizontal forms on principal $\mathbb{S}^1-$bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, principal-bundles, fibration

Assume that $M$ is a principal $\mathbb{S}^1-$bundle, i.e. an $\mathbb{S}^1-$manifold with the property that the action $M\times \mathbb{S}^1\to M$ is free (no fixed points) and the orbits $\mathcal{O}_p:=\{p\cdot\lambda: \lambda\in \mathbb{S}^1\}$ are precisely the fibers of a surjective submersion $h:M\to B$. Let's consider, moreover, the following vector field,
$$V_p=\left.\dfrac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} p\cdot e^{2\pi i t}$$

I want to prove that $\forall \mu\in \Omega^k(B)$, $\omega:=h^*(\mu)\in \Omega^k(M)$ is an horizontal form, i.e. the interior product $\iota_V(\omega)=0$. Any hint on how to do this?

In other words I have,
$$\forall p\in M \quad \exists \lambda\in \mathbb{S}^1\quad  s.t.\quad p\cdot \lambda\neq p \quad \text{and} \quad $$$$\mathcal{O}_p:=\{p\cdot \lambda: \lambda\in \mathbb{S}^1\}=h^{-1}(h(p))$$
For example, if $k=1$, then 
$(\iota_V(h^*(\mu)))_p=(h^*(\mu))_p(V_p)=\mu_{h(p)}((dh)_p(V_p))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$i_V\omega(u_1,...,u_{k-1})=i_Vh^*\mu(u_1,...,u_{k-1})=\mu(dh(V),dh(u_1),..,dh(u_{k-1}))=\mu(0,dh(u_1),..,dh(u_{k-1}))=0$

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more the last two steps?

Comment: $dh_p(V_p)=0$ since $h(p.e^{2\pi t})=h(p), {d\over{dt}}_{t=0}h(p.e^{2\pi t})=dh_p(V_p)=0$.

Comment: Is it always true that a form is zero if it has an argument equal to zero? Why?

Comment: A linear map evaluated on the $0$ vector gives $0$. Forms are multilinear, i.e., linear in each variable.